# Getting error "env: bash\r: No such file or directory" when running SH script

Tags: windows, bash, macos, unix

When I run a bash script, I'm getting the error message

`env: bash\r: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the bash script on windows, chances are you have CRLF line endings instead of just LF.

Changing the line endings to LF should fix this problem. I was writing in VSCode, so I simply clicked CRLF in the bottom right corner and changed it to LF.

`dos2unix` is also a popular program to perform this change for you.

Comment: What is the purpose of this question answer by you in the same minute on a trivial topic that already has plenty of answers in stackoverflow?

Comment: @LéaGris Apologies? I ran the issue described above, couldn't find a solution on SO and was hoping to save someone hassle in the future... No need to roast me mate

Comment: Like I said "...couldn't find a solution on SO". I'm not gonna argue with you. Feel free to vote to delete my question and answer.

Comment: No need to apologize. I understand. I thought a joke could ease it. Anyway @thatotherguy already marked this as duplicate. Nothing more todo.

Comment: ha no worries, cheers!